# Join automatically to multiple MUCs

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd

Is is possible to automatically join to multiple MUCs after login?

As I user I would like to login to the client and immidiately see many MUCs that I can open.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clients typically use [MUC bookmarks](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0402.html) to discover the regular MUCs of the user and automatically join the MUCs which are tagged 'autojoin' in their bookmark entry.

Comment: Do you know if that's faster load than joining to each one having JIDs? What is the difference between having MUC JIDs and to join to each one than having autojoin bookmark?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. Bookmarks are just used to get a list of MUC JIDs to join, which you ultimately may want to join.